# Zyxel GS1920 IPv6 switch does not provide hostname to DHCP server

Tags: ipv6, switch, hostname, zyxel

I have setup IPv6 in my network.

All Zyxel switches do not provide an hostname to the dhcp-server for IPv6.

For IPv4 they do!

Is there any setup, e.g. via dhcp-options, to make the switch transmit the hostname to the dhcp-server?